# How to put conditional queries inside cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a cursor ,which contain one query to calculating count on the basis of some group by problem. I  have to put some flag to execute the query
Suppose -  IF User_flag is 'Y' i want to calculate count on the basis of group by columns 
else 
I need whole table count along with few columns , no group by needed.

Simply I want to put condition inside cursor.

I have written query to calculate count , but I am not able to put condition-

```
 CURSOR EMP_detail SELECT  NULL t_name,
           NULL dep_name,
           NULL emp_name,
           COUNT(1) cnt  
      FROM emp_system emps,
     WHERE  
       AND emps.emp_id = 34167
       AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)  <=   TRUNC(valid_end)   
     GROUP BY NULL
   UNION
     SELECT NULL t_name,
           NULL dep_name,
           emp_name emp_name,
           COUNT(1) cnt   
      FROM emp_system emps,
     WHERE emps.emp_id = 34167
       AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)  <=   TRUNC(valid_end)   
     GROUP BY emp_name



CURSOR EMP_detail 
     IF User_flag ='Y' THEN
     SELECT  NULL t_name,
           NULL dep_name,
           NULL emp_name,
           COUNT(1) cnt  
      FROM emp_system emps,
     WHERE  
       AND emps.emp_id = 34167
       AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)  <=   TRUNC(valid_end)   
     GROUP BY NULL
     ELSE 
   UNION
     SELECT NULL t_name,
           NULL dep_name,
           emp_name emp_name,
           COUNT(1) cnt   
      FROM emp_system emps,
     WHERE emps.emp_id = 34167
       AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)  <=   TRUNC(valid_end)   
     GROUP BY emp_name
```

I need to perform above functionality .How can i achieve this in cursor itself.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already seem to be using PLSQL why not solve it there?

```
if user_flag='Y' then
  open your_cursor for select .. (query for when flag=Y)
else
  open your_cursor for select ... (query for when flag !=Y)
end if;
```